# What is the best practice for importing modules: absolute paths or relative paths?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

So I was working on a project where I defined all paths to other Python modules as absolute paths:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/user123/my_project/utilities')
import file_utilities
```

But then I had move the project to a different folder, which broke everything. I had to manually edit all paths to account for the folder change.

Is my initial use of absolute paths a bad choice? I initially avoided relative paths because I thought it would quickly become ugly:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../../../../utilities')
import file_utilities
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: Best practice is not to mess too much with `sys.path` at all.

Comment: Use a virtualenv to collect your code and your dependencies together, and that will ensure that your sys.path is correct.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how would you import `file_utilities` in this example?

Comment: @usualme: I'd use a virtual env or a buildout to include `file_utilities` closer to home.

Answer (score 1):

A handy solution would be to "move" a basepath, i.e. basepath = "/home/user123/" into a variable and address the path as

sys.path.append('{}/my_project/utilities'.format(basepath))

That would ugly relative notation and give you flexibility.

Comment: You'd use `os.path.join()` rather than formatting, however.