# In python3, how can I test a .py file which is under the subdirectory of the workspace root?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume that the file hierarchy is like:

```
|--WORKSPACE
   |--main.py
   |--subdir
   |  --__init__.py
   |  --sub1.py
   |  --sub2.py
```

In python2, I'd like to put some testing code below all the module code in submodule script file, and I can just run and check the result. Let the running root path be the WORKSPACE. e.g.
in main.py, I would write

```
from subdir import sub1
```

and in sub1.py:

```
from sub2 import something

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do some tests
```

in python3, I have to write like this:

```
from subdir.sub2 import something
```

when running directory is subdir, it will certainly stop with the import error...So I have to change pwd to the WORKSPACE. I don't think it's an elegant way, is there any other way to run in the subdir as an alternative?

Comment: `from sub2 import something` works for me in python3.

Answer (score 0):

It needs no directory name. For example, suppose

```
 ├── main.py
 └── subdir
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── sub1.py
    └── sub2.py
```

in main.py

```
from subdir import sub2
sub2.foo()
```

in /subdir/sub1.py

```
from sub2 import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

in /subdir/sub2.py

```
def foo():
    print("foo!")
```

Regardless of WORKSPACE wherever I run sub1 would work

Comment: All of you are using python3? It's odd, in my python3, I ran it correctly only under WORKSPACE... And what exact version of python are you using, 3.X?

Comment: @Traeyee I don't expect the behavior of `import` statments to depend on the working directory. Maybe you should write a more detailed description of what you are doing.

Comment: @Goyo Oh, sorry, I had messed it up. My  problem is from .sub2 import foo
(pay attention to the dot), it will say No module named '__main__.foo'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: @Traeyee Use `from sub2 import foo` instead.

Comment: @Goyo It's true, but pycharm cannot recognize clauses of this style so that it cannot     proceed with some smart grammatical assistance. That's where my problem exactly lies

Comment: Well that's completely missing from your question which instead suggest that is python3 not allowing you to use `from sub2 import foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do it that way. Organize your package and use relative imports inside it, without mentioning the parent package name.
If in need use subpackages. Lastly (or from the start depending on your mood), create a subpackage named `tests` containing all your tests. Import what you want to test in your package from there, just like you import from any other place inside your package. Use the module `unittest` to write `unittest.TestCase`'s inside tests subpackage.

From the package root execute `python -m unittest discover` see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest-test-discovery) or customize the tests run and output report, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#loading-and-running-tests). You probably want to study that help page for a while.

Now you can run all your tests at once, albeit there are ways to select only some.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you could add

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('subdir')

from subdir import sub1
```

to your `main.py`,
this way it'll get all the relative imports in that subfolder for you, no need to call the subfolder each time

and in `sub1.py` just

```py
from sub2 import foo
```

Comment: Well, a smart way

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what's wrong with this approach? I find it smarter than prepending namefolder. to all imports in that folder...

Comment: @lupodellasleppa There is nothing wrong, but see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26780255/what-is-the-best-practice-for-importing-modules-absolute-paths-or-relative-path), read in particular the comments by Martijn Pieters. Just don't abuse or depend much on that technique.